# Run Time Permissions to Access Fine Location

Tags: android, permissions, maps

I am generating a project for maps and to check the permissions I am trying to use if statement against `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` with the studio does not accept it

my code is as follows:

```
private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,getApplicationContext(),FINE_LOCATION)==
          PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `Manifest` in below line is imported from `import android.Manifest;`

```
 private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
```

And change this

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,getApplicationContext(),FINE_LOCATION)==
          PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
```

To

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,FINE_LOCATION)==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
```

Now it will work.Thanks!